# Python break if a condition stays false for some time

Tags: python

I am writing a program for real time pitch detection. Here's the outline of the code :-

```
def pitch_detection :

    result = []
    while True :

        // apply pitch detection algorithm

        if pitch_energy > threshold :
            result.append(pitch)

    return result
```

I want to brrak from the loop if `pitch_energy > threshold` is `False` for sometime

What I am doing right now is timeout the loop after sometime. 
Like this :-
[How would I stop a while loop after n amount of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293269/)

Comment: To break from the loop if the pitch_energy > threshold is False for 4 seconds .

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a counter and break if the condition is false a certain number of times?

Comment: Is there a way I could use "time elapsed" as condition to break

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the time whenever you make an append to the list. Then compare it to the current time when you don't make a correction. If the time since you last made an append is greater than some threshold, you break:

```
def pitch_detection :

    result = []
    start = time.time()
    MAX_TIME_ALLOWED = 5 # seconds
    while True :

        // apply pitch detection algorithm

        if pitch_energy > threshold :
            result.append(pitch)
            start = time.time() # reset the time when we append.
        else:
            if (time.time() - start) > MAX_TIME_ALLOWED:
                break

    return result
```

This assumes you actually want to use elapsed time to decide when to break. If you want to use number of iterations of the loop, just use a counter that starts at 0, and increment it in the else block, rather than `time.time()`.

```
def pitch_detection :

    result = []
    no_append = 0
    MAX_TIME_ALLOWED = 5 # seconds
    while True :

        // apply pitch detection algorithm

        if pitch_energy > threshold :
            result.append(pitch)
            no_append = 0
        else:
            no_append += 1
            if no_append > MAX_TIMES_ALLOWED:
                break

    return result
```

Comment: Simple and Concise. Thanks a lot! Saved me an hour of headache

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `alarm` to time yourself out after four seconds. It'll require some setup to get going, since you need a function and an exception class to use.

```
import signal

# Define a couple things.
class TimeoutException(Exception):
  pass

def timeout_handler(signum, frame):
  raise TimeoutException()

# Set the alarm handler.
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM,timeout_handler)

alarmOn = False
try:
  while True:

    # Pitch detection algorithm

    if pitch_energy <= threshold:
      # False condition - start your alarm.
      if not alarmOn:
        signal.alarm(4)
        alarmOn = True
    else:
      # True condition - turn off the alarm.
      alarmOn = False
      signal.alarm(0)
      result.append(pitch)

except TimeoutException: # This happens if four seconds pass without signal.alarm(0) being called.
  print "We're done."
  signal.alarm(0) # Turn the alarm off
```

The `signal.alarm()` function starts a timer with whatever value you give it, in seconds. If that many seconds pass without the alarm being reset, then a `SIGALRM` signal is sent. The way the code above works, it will catch that `SIGALRM` signal and throw our custom `TimeoutException`. This allows us to break out of the `while` loop, since we catch that exception.

EDIT: looking at dano's answer, it's entirely possible that this one is overly complicated. The main difference between ours is that this solution will immediately interrupt what you're doing if four seconds pass - that could stop your pitch detection algorithm right in the middle. dano's solution will always wait until that certain point in the code to check the time.

Comment: I was actually about to add a comment that mentions exactly what you put in your edit (stopping the processing right in the middle). That may or may not be desirable for the OP. If it's not desirable or they don't care, this is a bit over-engineered.