# forcing to end a function that accepts input using a timer

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, windows-10

I've tried using the the solution posted here:

[How would I stop a while loop after n amount of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293269/how-would-i-stop-a-while-loop-after-n-amount-of-time)

but that loop doesn't end with the function im running that accepts inputs. How do I force function5 to exit?

```
    while True:
                test = 0
                if test == 5 or time.time() > timeout:
                    print "time's out!"
                    break
                test = test - 1
                function5()
   def function5():
                receiver = raw_input("enter something: ")
```

Comment: Do you want to do this manually or do you want it to timeout automatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already identified your problem. This won't work because when you call raw_input() the program will wait forever until the user types something, and what you want is for the timeout to somehow interrupt raw_input().

Here is a *nix-only solution:

[Keyboard input with timeout in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout-in-python)

Comment: UPDATE: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3911477/7927496
Paul's code with thread seems do what I want to do. Although I haven't figured out how it works completely because threads are new to me. I still managed to tweak it a little bit to fit my code