# Break out of loop after some time Python

Tags: python, loops

I wanted to know how to move onto the next line of code after X time since this code is within a function. Currently if the code can't find the round number it continuously presses f resulting in the script getting stuck.

```
        if self.round in ("2-5"):
            """Levels to 5 at 2-5"""
            while arena_functions.get_level() < 5:
                self.arena.buy_xp_round() #presses f key
            print(f"\n[LEVEL UP] Lvl. {arena_functions.get_level()}")

        self.arena.fix_bench_state() #next line of code
```

I've tried many things but it usually results in the f key being pressed once then moving on to the next line. I want the script to keep pressings F in round 2-5 until the condition is met. If it can't meet the condition within the time limit then move onto the next line of code

Comment: can't you use the `break` keyword if the time limit has been reached within the while?

Comment: What should happen if the code is in the middle of doing something when the timer runs out? What are the rules for when it's allowed to stop?

Comment: you mean spam f until the condition is met or hold the key down until the condition is met?

Comment: Refer to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293269/how-would-i-stop-a-while-loop-after-n-amount-of-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `break` command to break out of the loop or use `continue` to break out of 1 iteration of the loop.

An example to break the loop after 10 seconds:

```py
from datetime import datetime 
start_time = datetime.now()

if self.round in ("2-5"):
            """Levels to 5 at 2-5"""
            while arena_functions.get_level() < 5:
                self.arena.buy_xp_round() #presses f key
                if ((datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds() > 10): # check if 10 seconds passed
                    break # break out of loop
            print(f"\n[LEVEL UP] Lvl. {arena_functions.get_level()}")

        self.arena.fix_bench_state() #next line of code
```

Answer (score 0):

I would insert inside the while loop a second condition, that activates after an X number of times (100 in the example).

```py
    limit = 100
    while arena_functions.get_level() < 5 or limit != 0:
                self.arena.buy_xp_round() #presses f key
                limit = limit - 1
```